# extract text from tex, remove latex tags

Tags: latex

I have some .tex files from which I want to receive the plain text without any latex tags such as \section{...} or \newpage.
Does anybody have any idea on how to achieve this?
I also have the .pdf file but when I just copy the code from there, some words get concatenated which is real bad.
Is there any tool you know?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[detex(1)](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/):

> Please see the [OpenDetex GitHub page](https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex) for the latest version of [OpenDetex](https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex). It is a more modern, derivative version of my original DeTeX.
>
> My legacy [DeTeX home page](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/index-legacy.html) is available [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/index-legacy.html).
>
> If you just want the legacy [detex-2.8.tar](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/detex-2.8.tar) source, you can get it [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/detex-2.8.tar).

Comment: Only works on ASCII tex files. If you're using xelatex and UTF-8 encoded tex files with non-ASCII chars, detex outputs junk for the non-ASCII chars.

Comment: It's open source, it could always be fixed.

Comment: Does `detex` allow me to ignore newline that exist in the middle of the line? @Charlie Martin

Comment: @Alper I honestly have no idea. It's open source, give it a try.

Comment: just tried it, it is bad, support for macro is way worse than pdflatex

Answer (score 9):

[opendetex](http://code.google.com/p/opendetex/)   is available both for windows and Linux

download the program opendetex from here 
http://opendetex.googlecode.com/files/opendetex-2.8.1.tar.bz2 
http://code.google.com/p/opendetex/downloads/list

Usage:
http://code.google.com/p/opendetex/wiki/Usage

extract it to any directory of your choice.
Say u extract it to Downloads directory.

make another directory of any name in that (optional. but its good if u create). say the directory name is “my_paper”. Put your paper in the “my_paper” directory. say your paper name is project.tex

Navigate through the path

```
cd ~/Downloads/opendetex
```

Run the command

```
detex -n my_paper/project.tex  > out.txt
```

generic form

```
detex -n full_path_to_tex_file.tex > output_text_file.txt
```

Comment: any idea who are the developers or how we can report bugs/issues?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not 100% what the OP requested, but maybe it is of some help.

There is `pdftotext` in [poppler-utils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)#poppler-utils). This can convert a PDF file to a TXT file via

```
pdftotext yourPDF.pdf
```

Of course this incurs the overhead of installing this package, but I think it's neglible, since it is the standard library to render PDF on Linux if I remember correctly, so if you have a PDF viewer installed (Think Evince or Okular), it will be installed already.

Find [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/228531/how-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-editable-text-using-the-command-line-in-linux/) some more instructions.