# Scan commands in a LaTeX File - JAVA

Tags: java, latex, java.util.scanner

In a project i have to prepare in JAVA I have a latex file with this format (Its an example part)

```
\begin{document}
% typeset front matter
\maketitle \thispagestyle{fancy}
\begin{abstract}
In this paper we present a new architecture of self-routing
switching networks called multi-log$_2\sqrt{N}$. This architecture
was considered by us in several earlier papers. We proved
condition for strict-sense nonblocking and rearrangeable operation
of this switching network. Strict-sense nonblocking
multi-log$_2\sqrt{N}$ switching networks for $N<128$ require less
switching elements than nonblocking multi-log$_2N$ switching
networks proposed by Lea \cite{lea90}. Rearrangeable
multi-log$_2\sqrt{N}$ switching networks for some value of $N$
requires less switching elements than nonblocking multi-log$_2N$
switching networks. In this paper we will consider a performance
of the proposed architecture when a single plane is used (i.e.
blocking one), and compare it with standard log$_{2}N$ switching
networks of the same capacity, as well as with multi-log$_{2}N$
switching networks of the same cost.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
In future telecommunication networks switches of great capacity
will be needed. This capacity refers to both the total throughput
of a switch and the number of ports served by the switch. When the
number of ports and their bit transfer rate increase, then the
less time a control unit has to determine how to route packets
through a switching network of a switch. Therefore, switching
networks with self-routing capability are particularly attractive
candidates for packet switching in broadband networks. The most
popular architecture of such self-routing switching networks is a
switching network composed of $d\times d$ switches arranged in
log$_{d}N$ stages \cite{lea-multirate-94}. In most popular
solutions $d=2$. An example is a banyan network, other equivalent
architectures, however, like baseline, omega, or perfect shuffle
networks are also well known \cite{Pat98}.
```

I want to make a program that ignores the commands and looks only for normal words and store them in a different text file. What tool can i use for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract text from tex, remove latex tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829408/extract-text-from-tex-remove-latex-tags)

Comment: I dont want to remove the commands, The file must stay untouched.

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm quite sure `detex` does not change its input file, it prints to standard output. The linked question shows how to store that output in a different file.

Comment: Τhe problem is that i want to do it with a Java program, not with an external tool.

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this in Java?

Comment: Its a project i have to prepare

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)